# Ambiguous pointer; <SiHCollection> is ambiguous

Tags: c++, ambiguous

below I've posted my code which is meant to store hits collections in HCE (hit collection of events).
The code compiles successfully but on running the program, the following error is printed to the terminal seven times:
< SiHCollection> is ambiguous.

I have a feeling it is because I am using namespace std although I don't know how to amend the code. Any thoughts?

```
#include "SiSD.h"
#include "SiHit.h"

#include "G4HCofThisEvent.hh"
#include "G4Step.hh"         
#include "G4ThreeVector.hh"  
#include "G4SDManager.hh"    
#include "G4ios.hh"          
#include "G4UnitsTable.hh"

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 

using namespace std;

extern ofstream outfile;    

SiSD::SiSD(G4String name)
:G4VSensitiveDetector(name)          
{                                                                                                                           

collectionName.insert("SiHCollection");                                        

}

SiSD::~SiSD(){ }

void SiSD::Initialize(G4HCofThisEvent* HCE)         
{
 SiHCollection = new SiHitsCollection(SensitiveDetectorName, 
 collectionName[0]);


static G4int HCID = -1;

 if(HCID<0)
  {
    HCID = G4SDManager::GetSDMpointer()->GetCollectionID(collectionName[0]);
  }

 HCE->AddHitsCollection(HCID, SiHCollection);
}

G4bool SiSD::ProcessHits(G4Step* aStep, G4TouchableHistory*)    
{
 if(aStep->GetTrack()->GetTrackID() > 0) {
 G4double edep = aStep->GetTotalEnergyDeposit();

 if(edep==0) return false;

 SiHit* aHit = new SiHit();
 aHit->SetEdep(edep);
 SiHCollection->insert(aHit);
  return true;
} else return false;
}
```

Comment: You think the line numbers the compiler spit out are irrelevant?

Comment: Don't summarize error messages. They contain important information, and summarizing when you're lost loses that information.

Comment: The compiler didn't output any line numbers, the only output is when I run the program; the exact output is:
<SiHCollection> is ambiguous.
<SiHCollection> is ambiguous.
<SiHCollection> is ambiguous.
<SiHCollection> is ambiguous.
<SiHCollection> is ambiguous.
<SiHCollection> is ambiguous.
<SiHCollection> is ambiguous.

Comment: Looks like output from the undisclosed part of the code, probably from one of the G4Wotsits.

Comment: A quick grep through the code suggests that it's because you have several "hits collections" with the same name. (Assuming that the G4Wotsits are from Geant.)

Comment: Hi Molbdnilo, yes this code is written for GEANT4 and I think you might be right! This code was initially written for placing one detector; I think I need to have some way of assigning each detector to a new collection name. Fingers crossed my tutor sends me some example code to help; I don't suppose you'd have any idea how to rectify this?

Comment: I managed to solve it. I had two pointers named 'event' that were called in two separate methods. Thanks for your help

Comment: @DavidMillership don't update a question as "Solved". Instead, mark an answer as accepts or, if there are no correct answers, add your own answer.